If $\pi$ is a coupling between $f_*\mu_X, g_*\mu_Y$ and $\pi = (f(x),g(y))_* \sigma$, then $\sigma$ is a coupling between $\mu_X,\mu_Y$
I am trying to read this paper: "The Gromov-Wasserstein distance between networks and stable network invariants" https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04337. In this paper, they have the following Lemma.

Lemma 28. Let $X,Y$ be Polish, and let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$, $g:Y\to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable. Let $T:X\times Y\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a map $(x,y)\mapsto (f(x),g(y))$. Then we have:
$\begin{equation} T_* \mathscr{C}(\mu_X, \mu_Y) = \mathscr{C}(f_*\mu_X, g_*\mu_Y)\tag*{}\end{equation}$

Here, $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ are Borel probability measures on $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and $f_*$ represents the pushforward of a measure by a mapping $f$, and $\mathscr{C}(\mu_X,\mu_Y)$ is the space of coupling measures between $\mu_X,\mu_Y$ i.e. the space of probability measures $\pi$ on $X\times Y$ such that $\pi(A\times Y) = \mu_X(A), \pi(X\times B)=\mu_Y(B)$ for Borel measurable sets $A\subset X,B\subset Y$.
The direction $\subset$ is trivial, so the issue is the $\supset$ direction. When they prove this direction, they use this lemma. Here, an analytic set is the continuous image of a Polish space.

Lemma 27. Let $X$,$Y$ be analytic subsets of Polish spaces equipped with the relative Borel $\sigma$-fields. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a subjective, Borel-measurable map. Then, for any $\nu\in \textrm{Prob}(Y)$(the space of Borel probability measures), there exists $\mu\in \textrm{Prob}(X)$ such that $\nu=f_*\mu$.

What they basically do to prove $\supset$ is that they take $\pi\in \mathscr{C}(f_*\mu_X,g_*\mu_Y)$, and then apply Lemma 3.1 to $T$, which gives us $\sigma \in \textrm{Prob}(X\times Y)$ such that $T_*\sigma = \pi$. However, they just say that this $\sigma$ belongs to $\sigma \in \mathscr{C}(\mu_X,\mu_Y)$ and don't give the proof of it.
Since this is a crucial step of the proof, I tried to give proof myself, but I couldn't do so. The main question is: Is Lemma 28 True?

@NateEldredge Sorry, I was looking at a different version. It is Lemma 27, 28 on Arxiv.

I agree, it looks like a gap in the paper.  I don't know offhand if the claimed Lemma 28 is actually true

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883414/realize-a-coupling-in-the-target-space-via-a-measure-on-the-source-space looks like it might have been asked by one of the paper's authors, given the similarity between Michael Greinecker's answer and what's in the paper (e.g. the reference to Varadarajan).  But in that question they didn't specify that $\nu$ is supposed to couple $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$, and Michael's answer doesn't give such a coupling.

So perhaps you should remove the trivially false question at the end of your post, and simply ask whether Lemma 28 is true.

@NateEldredge Thanks for suggestion, I incorporated your advice.

Just rephrasing my previous comment: certainly there can exist $\sigma$ that satisfy $T_* \sigma = \pi$ but do not couple $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ (and nothing in the paper's proof rules then out), so the question is whether there exist a $\sigma$ that does do so.

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}\newcommand{\tla}{\tilde\lambda}\newcommand{\tmu}{\tilde\mu}$Yes, Lemma 28 is true.
Let us restate it (ignoring the trivial inclusion $\subseteq$) as follows.

Lemma 1: Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be Polish spaces. For each $j\in\{1,2\}$, let $f_j\colon X_j\to\R$ be a measurable function and let $\mu_j$ be a probability measure over $X_j$; in what follows, it is always assumed that $j\in\{1,2\}$. Let $\pi$ be any probability measure over $\R^2:=\R\times\R$ with marginals $\mu_j\circ f_j^{-1}$, so that $\pi(B_1\times\R)=\mu_1(f_1^{-1}(B_1))$ and $\pi(\R\times B_2)=\mu_2(f_2^{-1}(B_2))$; here and in what follows, $B_1$ and $B_2$ stand for arbitrary Borel subsets of $\R$.
Then there is a probability measure $\la$ over $X_1\times X_2$ with marginals $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ such that $\pi=\la\circ(f_1,f_2)^{-1}$, that is,
\begin{equation}
    \la(f_1^{-1}(B_1)\times f_2^{-1}(B_2))=\pi(B_1\times B_2). \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation}

Proof.
Let $\F_j$ be the $\si$-algebra generated by $f_j$, and then let $\F:=\F_1\otimes\F_2$.  Then the condition
\begin{equation}
    \tla(f_1^{-1}(B_1)\times f_2^{-1}(B_2))=\pi(B_1\times B_2) \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation}
defines a unique probability measure $\tla$ on the $\si$-algebra $\F$ with marginals $\tmu_j:=\mu_j|_{\F_j}$.
The condition $\mu_{j,A_j}(C):=\mu_j(A_j\cap C)$ for $C\in\F_j$ defines a measure $\mu_{j,A_j}$ on $\F_j$ that is absolutely continuous wrt $\tmu_j$; here and in what follows, $A_j$ stands for an arbitrary member of the Borel $\si$-algebra over $X_j$. Let $p_{j,A_j}$ stand for the Radon--Nikodym density of $\mu_{j,A_j}$ wrt $\tmu_j$, so that $p_{j,A_j}$ is $\F_j$-measurable and $\mu_j(A_j\cap C)=\int_C p_{j,A_j}\,d\tmu_j$ for all $C\in\F_j$.  Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Polish spaces, without loss of generality $p_{j,A_j}$ is regular, that is, countably additive in $A_j$ (see e.g. this and this). Also, if $A_j\in\F_j$, then $p_{j,A_j}=1_{A_j}$.
So, letting now
\begin{equation}
    \la(A_1\times A_2):=\int_{X_1\times X_2}p_{1,A_1}(x_1)p_{2,A_2}(x_2)\,\tla(dx_1\times dx_2), 
\end{equation}
we get a probability measure $\la$ over $X_1\times X_2$ with marginals $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ such that $\la|_\F=\tla$ and hence $\pi=\la\circ(f_1,f_2)^{-1}$. $\quad\Box$

As noted in the comment by Nate Eldredge, the proof in the linked paper is insufficient (as witnessed by, say, the example with $f=0$ and $g=0$ in a previous, now deleted comment by Nate Eldredge).
